# Compare values in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have a variable like so:

```
columnData = new Array(columnWidth, columnIndex);
```

both values are numbers

and then I want to do the following:

```
thiscolumnWidth = columnData[1] WHERE columnData[2] == cellIndex;
```

the idea is that I want the `thiscolumnWidth` to be the value of the first value in the array of `columnData` where the second value `columnData` matches the `cellIndex` value.

The reason for doing it this way is because all of this sits inside a foreach loop so therefore it needs to find the correct array in memory! This **ALL WORKS** apart from the Where clause which doesn't exist in JS.

Can anyone help? Cheers

Comment: Take a look at JSINQ (LINQ to Objects for Javascript)  http://jsinq.codeplex.com/ - It does a good job of letting you quickly query arrays & objects using SQL-like queries.

Comment: BTW... array indexing starts at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using JSLINQ you could simply do something like:

```
if (columnData[2] == cellIndex){
    thiscolumnWidth = columnData[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl, developed in WSH, but will work anywhere JavaScript runs.

```
var aValues = new Array();
aValues[100] = 123;
aValues[200] = 234;
aValues[300] = 234;

var nValue = aValues[100];
WScript.Echo( nValue );

var nValue = aValues[200];
WScript.Echo( nValue );
```